# JQuery not initializing object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm attempting to dynamically create a button using JQuery to create the button, initialize it, and insert it into the DOM. When the following code executes, an element is added into the DOM, however instead of being:

```
<input value="button">Click Me</input>
```

The item in the DOM is just:

```
<input>
```

Not sure why the properties are not being initialized or a complete htlm element is being created.

```
var list = $("#rootElement").find(".listclass");
var button = $("<input/>", {
    type : button,
    value : "Click Me"
});
list.append(button)
```

Comment: change button to "button" and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

### Do this instead

IMO it's much more easy.

```js
var list = $("#rootElement").find(".listclass");
list.append('<input type="button" value="Click Me"/>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rootElement">
  <div class="listclass">
  </div>
</div>
```

BTW: `<input>` tag doesn't accept content.

```
<input value="button">Click Me</input>  <-- wrong
```

should be

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me"/> <-- good
```

or just

```
<button>Click Me</button>
```

### Your code fixed

You forgot put quotes in button.

```js
var list = $("#rootElement").find(".listclass");
var button = $("<input>", {   
    type: 'button', // here forgot quotes
    value: 'Click Me'
});
list.append(button)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="rootElement">
      <div class="listclass">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `type: "button"` instead of `type: button`

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/su9m81yu/2/